# Syntax error in SQL query: unexpected 'SUM' (sum)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following query and I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'sum(sl.duration) as duration, sum(sl.quantity_loss) as
>   quantity_loss'

```
SELECT 
   lr.uid AS loss_reason_uid,
   gl.uid AS gl_uid,
   lt.uid AS lt_uid,
   SUM(sl.duration * b.marginal_value_downtime) AS value_loss where en.state = 'downtime',
   SUM(sl.quantity_loss * p.marginal_value) as value_loss where en.state != 'downtime',
   SUM(sl.duration) AS duration,
   SUM(sl.quantity_loss) AS quantity_loss,
   COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    sub_losses AS sl
```

Any idea why is this syntax error occurring?

Comment: You need a `group by` and you can't use a `where` for a `sum`. A `where` clause is applied to the query, not an attribute. You may want to `sum` over a `case` expression.

Comment: Show your full query how these aliases are defined `en`,`lr`,`gl` ...

Comment: You are renaming two calculated values to `value_loss`!

Comment: You  need to move the conditions to inside the SUM()'s. Use case expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks @HoneyBadger for guiding.

```
SELECT 
    lr.uid AS loss_reason_uid,
        gl.uid AS gl_uid,
        lt.uid AS lt_uid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN en.state = 'downtime' THEN sl.duration * b.marginal_value_downtime ELSE sl.quantity_loss * p.marginal_value END) AS value_loss,
        SUM(sl.duration) AS duration,
        SUM(sl.quantity_loss) AS quantity_loss,
        COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    sub_losses AS sl
```

Comment: You still need a `group by` to get reliable results. This query will error out in the newer mysql version (unless in compatibility mode).

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: Except above comments it is not allowed to use same `ALIAS` or `COLUMN NAME` more than once in a single block of query so I have given `value_loss1` to make is unique.

```
SELECT 
   lr.uid AS loss_reason_uid,
   gl.uid AS gl_uid,
   lt.uid AS lt_uid,
   SUM(CASE WHEN en.state = 'downtime' THEN (sl.duration * b.marginal_value_downtime) ELSE 0 END) AS value_loss,
   SUM(CASE WHEN en.state != 'downtime' THEN (sl.quantity_loss * p.marginal_value) ELSE 0 END) AS value_loss1,
   SUM(sl.duration) AS duration,
   SUM(sl.quantity_loss) AS quantity_loss,
   COUNT(*) AS count
FROM sub_losses AS sl
GROUP BY lr.uid,
         gl.uid,
         lt.uid
```

Comment: I needed only `value_loss` column actually. I have posted my solution. Thanks for your answer.